# How does negative index work with `Array#[]=`?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I tried to see how `Array#[]=` works, and played around:

```
enum[int] = obj → obj
enum[start, length] = obj → obj
enum[range] = obj → obj
```

**Question 1**

I have one array `b` holding `nil` at its `0` index.

```
b = []
b[0]   # => nil
```

I tried to replace `nil` with integer `10` in the code below.

```
b[-1] = 10 # => IndexError: index -1 too small for array; minimum: 0
```

Why doesn't the code above work, but the ones below do? In case of an array with size `1`, why are the indices `0` and `-1` treated differently?

```
b[0] = 5   # => 5
b[-1] = 10 # => 10
```

**Question 2**

I created an array of size `2`, and did the following:

```
a = [1,2]

a[-3] = 3       # => IndexError: index -3 too small for array; minimum: -2
a[-3] = [3]     # => IndexError: index -3 too small for array; minimum: -2
a[-3..-4] = [3] # => RangeError: -3..-4 out of range
```

I believe that negative index never increases the size of an array, but I don't know why. Why did the code below succeed?

```
a[-2..-3] = [3,4] #=> [3, 4]
```

Comment: Good question, trying to find out a reason

Comment: @Arindam thanks for your complement.. :)

Comment: empty array like `b = []` does *not* hold `nil`. it just returns `nil` if value at given index does not exist. `> b[6789]` => `nil`

Comment: @DavidUnric Humm you are correct absolutely.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest you to take a look at the first para in [Array documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html). It surprisingly says: “A negative index is assumed to be relative to the end of the array—that is, an index of -1 indicates the last element of the array, -2 is the next to last element in the array, and so on.”

That means, that you may set `a[-N]`th element if and only `|N| <= a.size`. That’s why `a = [1,2] ; a[-3] = 3` fails (3 > 2).

On the other hand, there is [likely] not documented feature for ruby arrays: `a[INBOUNDS_IDX..NONSENSE_IDX]=SMTH` will **insert** `SMTH` **before** `INBOUNDS_IDX` index:

```
a=[1,2]
a[2..0]='a'
a[2..1]='b'
a[2..-100]='c'
# ⇒ [1, 2, "c", "b", "a"]
a[2..-1]='q'
# ⇒ [1, 2, "q"]
```

Nonsense here means “less than INBOUNDS_IDX, **and** not treatable as index in an negative notation” (that’s why `a[2..-1]` in the example above is treated as `a[2..(a.size - 1)]`.)

Comment: I didn't find the answer of the `a[-2..-3] = [3,4] #=> [3, 4]` of this I think. Could you point me here?

Comment: @LoveConcept `a[-2..-3] = [3,4] #=> [3, 4]` means `[3,4]` is the value returned from `Array#[]` method. If you’ll print `a` value with `puts a` you’ll see `#⇒[3,4,1,2]` as expected.

Comment: if you try `a = [1,2]` and then `a[-3] = 5` would produce error as `IndexError: index -3 too small for array; minimum: -2`. But then tried `a[-2..-4] =15` works. Here I am confused. Could you please help me to understand this concept? and new array looks like `>> a
#=> [15, 1, 2]`. Here array set or add new element with the help of negative index too, but why not in the first attempt?

Comment: I don’t think I can explain it better, than I already did in my comment (starting with “On the other hand…” and until the end of comment.)

Comment: Humm, you did it. Really this thing was not documented. But thanks to express the fact. `+1` to you.

Comment: The only one you may see there is mine :-)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25036/discussion-between-loveconcept-and-mudasobwa)

Comment: i think it's not properly explained. the point is if `Range` is used for array slicing, it does not "expand" it but just takes its bounds with `#first` and `#last` methods. Now it starts to make a sense.

Answer (score 0):

Observation #1

The -1 index is related to the last element, if the array has no size, [], you can't use it until you initialize it with one or more elements.

Observation #2:

Yes, you are right, the negative index never increases size of the array, it only references a concrete existing position in the array.

Don't think the array is circular—the 0 index clued to the N-1 index—so you can't use any negative index thinking that it's valid.

Comment: If so then how would you explain `a[-2..-3] = [3,4]` ?

Answer (score 0):

**Q1:**

An empty array has 0 elements, so when you try to set its element 0, with negative index `-1`, it will give an error. 
Because negative index cycles through the array from the end.

So 
`a = []; a[-1] = 3` makes it impossible to

a) get the element at last position, since its null

b) set its value. since it was never captured.

`a[0] = 5` will work because you are telling the compiler to

a) grab the first element,

b) create one if not present, and then assign that to the value you requested.

See [official api doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) specifically mentioning positive index can grow size, negative index past the beginning of the array raises an error.

**Q2:**

The above explanation almost answers the second question as well.

Given `a = [1,2]`

`a[-3] = 3` causes the first point of break. You are trying to access the 3rd element from the end, which does not exist. By design it breaks down.

While `a[-2..-3]` is within the capture range of the defined array.

You ask the interpreter to capture the second element from the last (1st from the front in this case), and try to invoke a range which is asking it to increase the array's size, and populate it with whatever you requested.

Happily, all is still well and as desired. Good to know.

Comment: “and try to invoke a range”—that’s not quite correct. `a[-2..-3]` is treated _exactly_ as `a[-2..0]` and both these ranges are, generally speaking, empty.

Comment: @mudasobwa wrong, they are *not treated* the same as `a[-2..0]` slices array with a non-empty range [-2, -1, 0] within a.size bounds.

Comment: @DavidUnric would you please provide a living example of an array having not exactly two elements, where result of applying `a[-2..-3]=SMTH` differs from `a[-2..0]=SMTH`? If no, please, consider they _are treated the same_. By “ranges are empty” I (not quite distinctly, though) meant “results of applying `Array#[]` are empty”.