# Compare consecutive values in an arr and swap them if needed

Tags: arrays, ruby

First of all, I'm pretty new to Ruby (few days).

I'm trying to go through an array, checking if the difference is greater than expected and if it is I want to swap the elements. In Java I would do it something like this:

```
int[] arr = {1, 10, 3, 28, 13};
int curr = 0;
int next = 1;
while (next < arr.length) {
 if (arr[curr] - arr[next] > 10) {
  int temp = arr[curr];
  arr[curr] = arr[next];
  arr[next] = temp;
 }
 curr++;
 next++;
}
```

Is there an elegant way to achieve this in Ruby? I can translate this code to Ruby code but it feels a little bit odd to do it like this in Ruby.

Thanks

Edit: I don't need to sort it in a standard way. This is a simplification of a problem I have. The array is already sorted on different property and this is only a sanitisation part that goes in O(n).

Edit2: I have an array of objects that are sorted by id. Those objects have another property that is for example, counter, that only needs to be checked with neighbouring objects. If the condition that the diff between counters is > 10 I should switch them. Don't be bothered with that then the other elements aren't in correct order :)

Comment: Are you trying to implement bubble sort or something?

Comment: Well no, even though I admit, it looks like I am :) I just need to reorder some elements in an array according to a very specific condition. I simplified it in the question but the point is the same.

Comment: Do you need to do this in place?

Comment: What would be the result for that source array?

Comment: @idmean not necessary.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I only need to compare consecutive elements in one pass. It's already sorted out on different property.

Comment: @Neman: this is not the question I asked :) what's the expected result of this algorithm for this input data?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev in this example it would be [1, 10, 3, 13, 28]

Comment: How `3` could stay intact?

Comment: @mudasobwa because 10 - 3 isn't larger than 10

Comment: @Neman gotcha, updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do this - this is simple iteration for indices `0` to `Array#size - 2`, we swap the elements if the condition is true.

```
arr = [1, 10, 3, 28, 13]
(0...arr.size - 1).each do |i|
    arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i] if (arr[i] - arr[i+1]) > 10
end
p arr
#=> [1, 10, 3, 13, 28]
```

Comment: This for me looks the most readable. I do have one question though. Why the `if` after the swap takes place? Is that a common thing with Ruby? I would write `if (arr[i] - arr[i+1]) > 10 arr[i], arr[i+1] = arr[i+1], arr[i]`

Comment: Its more readable I guess - in a small conditional statements, its better to focus on what is being done and then think of conditions under which that will happen.

Comment: And if I had for example more than one condition like `(arr[i] - arr[i+1]) > 10 && (arr[i] - arr[i+1]) < 20`?

Comment: Pick whichever is more readable - there is no strict rule....one should be able to understand code.

Answer (score 1):

```
arr = [1, 10, 3, 28, 13]
arr.each_with_index do |num, index|
  if (index + 1 < arr.size) && (arr[index] - arr[index + 1]) > 10
    arr[index], arr[index+1] = arr[index + 1], arr[index]
  end
end
```

Comment: You could remove these unneeded parentheses from the if.

Comment: `with_index` is redundant since one might use negative indices in ruby arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Not inplace solution:

```
arr = [1, 10, 3, 28, 13]
diff = 10

arr.inject([]) do |memo, el|
  (memo << el).tap do |a|
    a[-1], a[-2] = a[-2], a[-1] if a.size > 1 && a[-2] - a[-1] > diff
  end
end
```

What’s going on here:

- [`arr.inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) is a reducer, it starts with empty array and fills it with elements;
- `tap` passes a receiver to the block given, returning self back;
- next line swaps two last elements if and only there are more than one and their difference is greater than a given value.

Comment: @idmean In my world there are no one thing less elegant than `while` loop. Oh, wait: `if` condition is.

Comment: If I encountered this block of code in a program it would take me longer to figure out what it does compared to a while loop.

Comment: @idmean: agree with you here.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I personally switched to “functional treatment” of code, since I am successfully leaving ruby for erlang/elixir. But since my first line of code, while loops require from me the highest concentration because an amount of entities in while loop is usually N times greater than map-reduce (notice, please, that we have _no_ index here at all.)

Comment: @mudasobwa What I have trouble understanding here is the negative index like in `a[-1]` and `a[-2]`. Care to explain?

Comment: @Neman `a[-1]` stays for “very last,” `a[-2]` stays for the “second from the end.” http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049744/how-does-negative-index-work-with-array