# Why does string[1..-1] work but not string[-3..1]

Tags: ruby

The following block will display `ruit`

```
puts "fruit"[1..-1]
```

because the index starts at 1, and I think -1 represents infinity in this case

```
f  r  u  i  t

0  1  2  3  4
```

But if I want to use a reverse index, it doesn't work.

By the same logic I would expect this to return `ruit`, as the 0 represents infinity

```
puts "fruit"[-4..0]

f    r   u   i   t

-5  -4  -3  -2  -1
```

However this actually returns nothing.  Trying it again with a 1 instead of a 0

```
puts "fruit"[-4..1]

f    r   u   i   t

-5  -4  -3  -2  -1
```

It just returns `r`

--

Trying it with a 5 instead of a 4

```
puts "fruit"[-5..1]

f    r   u   i   t

-5  -4  -3  -2  -1
```

Some progress is made, it returns `fr`.

--

However it would seem I don't understand reverse indexes.  Does the `-1` in `[1..-1]` not mean infinity?  Why doesn't it work when you try to do the reverse?

Comment: I'd have a look at the ruby array docs, 0 means the first element [-3..1] goes from the 3rd last element to the second and so returns nothing. http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html look at accessing elements. The -1 in [1..-1] means the last element.

Comment: I've had a look at this, the only thing I don't understand is that [1..-1] would be similarly illogical.  It would go from the 2nd element to the first element to the last element and then end

Comment: Ruby works from left to right so it goes 2nd up to last(5th) rather than 2nd down and round.

Comment: I think I see what you mean.  I was picturing this acting like an incremental backwards for loop, where it prints element 1, then 0, then -1.  However, it seems that it will always increment upwards by 1.  In this case, the -1 on the end of the range is not taken as a literal value but rather as a pointer to the last element, which ends up actually being a positive 4 in this context.  Does that sum it up correctly?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes, negatives are a reference from the end of a list, positives from the beginning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negative numbers aren't "infinite", they simply represent counting from the end of the string. `-1` is the last character, `-2` is the second last.

```
"abcde"[-1]
#=> "e"
```

If you're doing ranges they should always be *lowest*..*highest* and in the case of `String#[]` you have to avoid wrapping around the end of the string. Your example with `-5..1` actually wraps around, so Ruby gives up and goes with `0..1` instead. Try not to mix and match negative and positive values.

`0` never represents infinity, it represents the beginning of the string. What you're experiencing here is the method trying to make do with bad arguments.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "gives up" or "instead". `[-5..1]` is equivalent to `[0..1]`.

Comment: @sawa The `String#[]` method refuses to deal with positive and negative values in the range, so it seems to just default to interpreting that as `0..1`. `-5..-1` reproduces the whole string, `-5..0` is interpreted as `0..0`.

Comment: It simply is that the index `-1` is equivalent to the index `4` and the index `-5` is equivalent to the index `0` here.

Comment: @sawa Something like that. Mixing negative and positive values seems to be a big issue.

Comment: I appreciate the responses.  As I commented above, I was picturing this acting like  a for loop that incremented backwards by -1.  However now I understand that it will always increment forwards from left to right, in which case the -1 really acts like a pointer to what is the last element.  This was a bit confusing for me coming from a different language.  Thanks again.

Comment: "If you're doing ranges they should always be *lowest..highest*..." I disagree. Of course, reverse ranges can't be iterated over and so shoudn't be used in that context, but in this context there isn't a more succinct way to express "the elements from index *n* except the last *m* elements" than e.g. `"junkgoldtrash"[4...-5] # => "gold"`.

Comment: @Jordan That's an interesting case, but also one that would malfunction if you had a shorter string. At some point using *start*..*end* is more confusing than *start*,*length*.

Answer (score 3):

It is simply that negative indices represent the position counted from the end in such a way that for a positive index `i` and a negative index `j`, they express the same position if and only if

```
i % string.length == j % string.length
```

given that the absolute value of `i` and `j` are smaller than `string.length`.

The cases that you claim as not working are the cases where the beginning position is on the right side of the ending position.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049744/how-does-negative-index-work-with-array).

Short answer: in Ruby arrays, negative numbers signify the order from the end of the array, and since in Ruby

```
:001 > -0 == 0
 => true
```

then

```
"zero"[0] == "zero"[-0]
```

and you can't use a "negative zero" to refer to a different element.
So, the last element of an array is represented by -1. You can think of it as a negative array index that is one-based, as [God intended](https://gist.github.com/Momus/81fdbc49c98718e9b40982cf34199271).

Therefore, `[1..-1]` means count from the second element to the last element.

Comment: Why can't you have -0 (which equals 0) as an index?

Comment: @sawa since signed zeros are a bitter and acrimonious topic, why don't I just edit the amswer?

Comment: Now it makes sense.